# Наложение объектов друг на друга в OpenGL, находящихся на одинаковом расстоянии от точки наблюдения

Tags: opengl

**Вопрос**: Как наложить частично один объект на другой, если они находятся на одинаковом     расстоянии от точки наблюдения?

Я использую в программе `glTranslatef(x1,y1,z1)` и `glTranslatef(x2,y2,z2)`, где     `y1=y2`.  `x1,z1` и `x2,z2` подобраны таким образом, что объекты должны перекрывать друг друга.

На при отрисовке я наблюдаю неприятные артефакты.

Если я выставляю `y2 < y1`, то артефакты исчезают, но объекты накладываются некорректно.

Answer (score 1):

При включенном буфере глубины вы не можете контролировать как драйвера и железо нарисуют наложенные полигоны. В одной конфигурации может получиться микс из артефактов, а в другой выведется только один из полигонов.

Если вам действительно необходимо наложение, то при отрисовке накладываемых полигонов отключайте буфер глубины `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`.

Но имейте ввиду, что тогда "объекты" нарисованные между камерой и "наложенным полигоном", до наложения, будут затерты.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня была такая задумка но мне тоже показалось что такой вариант ненадежен. Я считал что OpenGL отрисовывает примитивы в том порядке как они представлены в программе, но почему тогда возникают такие проблемы?

Comment: Полигоны отрисовываються в том порядке в котором вы их передаете, включая порядок в массивах. Но с учетом буфера глубины, если он включен. Каждому пикселю задается глубина, при отрисовке следующего полигона сравниваются все его пиксели, те что ближе к нам отрисуются, остальные нет.

Comment: Да именно это я и имел ввиду когда говорил "OpenGL отрисовывает примитивы в том порядке как они представлены в программе". Если глубина одинаковая, то по какой причине возникают артефакты?

Comment: Если глубина "одинаковая" возникает неопределенная ситуация, на которую влияет множество факторов. Тут не только OpenGL решает какие пиксели стоит перерисовывать. Если же буфер глубины отключен, то новые полигоны всегда рисуются поверх всего отрисованного.